# Accessing the accelerometer in iOS while running in the background

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, iphone-6

I'm new to iOS programming. I'm wanting to write an app that has constant access to the accelerometer, and barometric pressure sensor of the iPhone 6, while running in the background.

In my research, I've found that people have done it using the Location Updates background mode, but this only worked for 10 minutes before the app was suspended (and this changed to 3 minutes in iOS 6?). I'd also read about using the audio background mode playing a mute sound as a way to work around that time limit. This seems like a substandard solution though.

I'm wondering then how an app something like [Sleep Cycle](http://www.sleepcycle.com/) does this, as it seems like it must have constant access to the accelerometer.

Comment: using location services or audio to trick the OS into getting more time is a sure way to get rejected from the app store.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by using CoreMotion framework.
You have to import CoreMotion framework, then `#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>` in your `appdelegate`.

Here `motionManager` is object of `CMMotionManager`.

`xData, yData, zData` are double values to store accelerometer data.

```
if (motionManager ==nil) {
    motionManager= [[CMMotionManager alloc]init];
}
[motionManager startAccelerometerUpdates];

[motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
    xData = accelerometerData.acceleration.x;
    yData = accelerometerData.acceleration.y;
    zData = accelerometerData.acceleration.z;
}];
```

You have to do it in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`.

You can then use these value of `xData, yData, zData` where ever you want by `appdelegate` object, even in background.

Comment: When I tried this, it stops reporting accel data when app is put in bg,

Comment: Have you added location services and background mode enabled in your application?